# How to load file line by line in Nim?

Tags: file, nim-lang

I want to load a large file line by line in Nim. I tried the following code snippet:

```
for line in lines "largefile.txt":
  echo line
```

However, this loads the entire file `largefile.txt` into memory which is not feasible when the file is very large > 30GB.

How can I iterate over a large file while holding only a single line in memory ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would happen, unless you import a non-standard `lines` iterator somewhere. The one [in lib/system.nim](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/09b6d8c0ca5f9b5590e58d90b987975f36df8dd6/lib/system.nim#L3044) reads the file line by line, just as you want it. And when I'm testing that with a large file, memory usage does remain constant, as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, Reimer Behrends is right. The `lines` function works as expected.

The issue was that my file had only escaped newline characters. As a result, Nim (correctly) reads the file as one large line.